# How to change/disabled Input text color in mobile browser?

Tags: html, css, forms, mobile, webforms

Following is the code, the problem is it works fine on desktop browsers i.e. red color for disabled input, but on a mobile browser it doesn't show red, instead its grey, any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>testing</title>
    <style>
    input[disabled] {
        color: #f55;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <form id="myForm" method="post" action="forms.php">
            <input type="text" name="username" value="Username" disabled> <br>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"> <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit"> <br>
        </form> 
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>testing</title>
    <style>
    input[disabled] {
        color: #f55;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width:1000px) {
        input[disabled]{
            color: #C90;
             font-weight:bold;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <form id="myForm" method="post" action="forms.php">
            <input type="text" name="username" value="Username" disabled> <br>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"> <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit"> <br>
        </form> 
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

You can use media queries for that and instead of putting this style in html document it would be more appropriate to keep external style sheet for long css....You can target different devices by setting maximum width for different devices in @media inside css